# How to clear all cache files in linux server ( RHEL 5)

Tags: linux, rhel5, cache

- How can i clear all cache and buffered files in linux server (RHEL 5) ?

Comment: @Kumar - you might find the following thread on cache useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/105606/deleting-linux-cached-ram

Comment: Someone may be able to suggest something else if you explained why you want to. vm/drop_caches wipes the OS's caches of files on disc; it has no semantic effect just kills performance, which makes it useful for performance testing and (mostly) nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this post it is explained how to do it:

[deleting linux cached ram](https://serverfault.com/questions/105606/deleting-linux-cached-ram)

but be sure to read the complete post for why or why not to clear the caches.

Answer (score 2):

As root: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: `sync && /sbin/sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same concerns about a heavy-handed cache on an embedded box running 2.6.15 (which does not have the proc file mentioned above).  I did some experiments and found that one way to force the cache to clear is to create a ramdisk, fill it up with a huge temp file, and then delete the file.  Works perfectly.  Of course, what I proved was that Linux will indeed release the cache when absolutely ncessary.  BTW changing swappiness to 0 or 100 had absolutely no observable effect on meminfo whatsoever.