# Linux Cache Clear for Storage Performance Testing

Tags: linux, storage, cache, performance

Is there any way to make linux remove from memory all cached disk data?  Our goal is to time some performance tests on various storage configurations and have each one start with a clean slate cache-wise.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/105606/deleting-linux-cached-ram

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$ sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: This same command is all I can find online, but I noticed it doesn't completely get rid of my cache. `free` and top still shows quite a bit of memory used up by some cache, and disk-intensive PostgreSQL queries are returning extremely fast run a second time, even though the cache has been supposedly cleared.