# Measure Linux IOPS for a running system

Tags: storage, linux, performance-monitoring, performance

How do I measure IOPS of a running Linux server? I know that the theoretical IOPS of a SATA drive is around 90 and enterprise 10k SAS/FC disk is 180. I want to know how much my running system is using currently?

Currently I am using iotop and iostat. But both utilities do not give the IOPS number.

btw, this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/234758). I am not looking for benchmarking my storage system, but figure out how much IOPS is being used by my current system.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Uhm... `iostat` on my system shows the IOPS:

```
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.00        64.00         0.00         64          0
```

Might want to look at upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What is the difference between tps and IOPs? Are they same?

Comment: They are the same thing.

Answer (score 19):

Install `sysstat` package if you don't have it already and then use command `sar -d 1`. Watch the `tps` column. It gives you at least the ballpark figure.

But remember that actual maximum number of IOPS varies heavily depending on your server workload. A server with lots of sequential access might get more IOPS than a one doing lots of random access.

Answer (score 6):

Look at `nmon` as an option for a nicer presentation of the same data.

http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

Comment: page no longer exists

Comment: This is HUGE.  Immediately showed me disk read is maxed out at 100%.  Time to provision more IOPS... thank you!  For ubuntu, it's as easy as `sudo apt install nmon`.

Comment: @colllin These days, you may want to use [Netdata](https://my-netdata.io) instead.